# Deploying a list instance to SharePoint 2010 error "Unable to find the default new form for list"

Tags: sharepoint

Having a problem deploying a list instance via a feature, which should really be a noddy task, I know. I have come across many a post with the same issue, but there is no resolution.

- I created the list in the UI with content and views.
- Exported the site template as WSP.
- Imported into Visual Studio the list instance, pages module and property bags.
- Copied into my new solution.
- Deploy list instance as a site-scoped feature.

List deploys fine with content and views. However, I receive the following error when trying to add a new item: “Unable to find the default new form for list”. The same applies for editing items.

Strangely, deploying via a web scoped feature works just fine.

I am thinking that this is probably something quite simple but cannot see it nor find a satisfactory resolution.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered almost the same thing this afternoon, and solved it. For some reason the schema.xml has an empty Forms tag. You need to replace it with the stock forms tag as described by Microsoft - I wrote it up here;

http://notes.jonbeckett.com/2012/04/20/missing-forms-schema-with-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio/

The Microsoft page I discovered it on is here;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459356.aspx

Comment: Hi, Jonathan, do you have experience in developing external lists with Visual Studio? I want to achieve that, but am quite stuck. It would be great if you could give any example, materials etc.